# How to update $scope immediately when dealing with non angular code?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have to deal with an non angular library and need to create a comunication between them.

```
<div id="MoipWidget" data-token="{{personaltoken}}" callback-method-success="successCB" callback-method-error="errorCB"></div>
```

Every time that the page is loaded, I have to get a token from my server.

```
$http.post('https://example.org', obj)
        .success(function(data){
            $scope.personaltoken = data.token;
            //Here I call the non angular library and I get and error telling me that the token is undefined.
            //If I run the code from inside a $timeout works as I need...

        })
        .error(function(data){
             alert('error');
        });
```

I've also tried to run inside $scope.$apply but I get an error telling that `$digest already in progress`

The non angularjs library that I have to call is simple is just two lines.

```
var settings = {} 
LibraryCall(settings);
```

How can I update the model immediately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried to use `$scope.$evalAsync` as @Kjell suggested but did not work.

After reading more about $scope, I've found what I needed.

```
$scope.$applyAsync(function(){
    var settings = {} 
    LibraryCall(settings);
});
```

`$scope.$applyAsync` will schedule the invocation of $apply to occur at a later time.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

Answer (score 1):

I removed the error callback for brevity, don't do it in your code :)

I suppose the code you call is asynchronous, if it's not, you should not have any $scope updating problem (because all angular promises call $apply already)...

This should work:

```
$http.post('https://example.org', obj).success(function(data){
    $scope.personaltoken = data.token;

    otherLibrary.doSomething(data.token, function(error, result) {
        $scope.changeSomething = 'toHey';
        $scope.$apply();
    });
});
```

This shoud also work:

```
$http.post('https://example.org', obj).success(function(data){
    $scope.personaltoken = data.token;

    otherLibrary.doSomething(data.token, function(error, result) {
        $scope.$apply(function() {
            $scope.changeSomething = 'toHey';
        });
    });
})
```

This shoud raise the `$digest already in progress` error, because $http does wrap the promise callback on a $apply call already.

```
$http.post('https://example.org', obj).success(function(data){
    $scope.personaltoken = data.token;
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        otherLibrary.doSomething(data.token, function(error, result) {
            $scope.changeSomething = 'toHey';
        });
    });
})
```

Comment: Hello, I've just updated the post with the library code. Is very simple but I can't change their code so I have to be able to use the code: LibraryCall(settings); without passing the token directly to the library. Their library will get the token from data-token="{{personaltoken}}" is there another way to do this?

Comment: OK! I did not understand the point. Kjell Ivar did answer your question :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using either $scope.$evalAsync() or $scope.$applyAsync().
They are made for stuff like this. It will execute the code later in time. Not that different from $timeout, but potentially faster.

```
$scope.$evalAsync(function(){
    var settings = {} 
    LibraryCall(settings);
})
```

Edit: Just to quote Ben Nadel on the difference between $timeout and $evalAsync, from [this post](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2605-scope-evalasync-vs-timeout-in-angularjs.htm):

> So, in essence, $scope.$evalAsync() combines the best of both worlds:
>   When it can (which is most of the time), it will evaluate your
>   expression in the same tick; otherwise, it will evaluate your
>   expression in a later tick, which is exactly what $timeout() is doing.